# Vault in Prod mode starts in Sealed state

Tags: vault, hashicorp

I installed vault in prod mode.
using this configuration -

```
ui = true

#mlock = true
#disable_mlock = true

storage "file" {
  path = "/opt/vault/data"
}

# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
  tls_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.crt"
  tls_key_file  = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.key"
}
```

after running the vault.service and checking for vault status, It is pre initialised and sealed and unable to unseal it. Please help

```
 vault status
Key                Value
---                -----
Seal Type          shamir
Initialized        true
Sealed             true
Total Shares       3
Threshold          2
Unseal Progress    0/2
Unseal Nonce       n/a
Version            1.11.0
Build Date         2022-06-17T15:48:44Z
Storage Type       file
HA Enabled         false
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need to do `vault operator init`, and do https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/operator/unseal or if you want to auto unseal you can use awskms or gcpkms